# Show red border for all invalid fields after submitting form angularjs

Tags: forms, validation, angularjs

I have a form in which I have some input fields. Some of them are **required** fields and some are **email** fields.

I am using HTML5 **required** attribute for required fields and **type="email"** attribute for email fields.

My question is after clicking on submit button i have to show **red border** for all the invalid fields.

This is my form:

```
<form name="addRelation">
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" data-ng-model="model.firstName"     id="FirstName" name="FirstName" required/><br/>
  <span class="text-error" data-ng-show="addRelation.submitted && addRelation.FirstName.$error.required">first Name is required</span><br/>
  <label>Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" data-ng-model="model.lastName" id="LastName" name="LastName" required/><br/>
  <span class="text-error" data-ng-show="addRelation.submitted && addRelation.LastName.$error.required">Last Name is required</span><br/>
  <label>Email</label>
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email" data-ng-model="model.email" id="Email" name="Email" required/><br/>
  <span class="text-error" data-ng-show="addRelation.submitted && addRelation.Email.$error.required">Email address is required</span><br/>
  <span class="text-error" data-ng-show="addRelation.submitted && addRelation.Email.$error.email">Email address is not valid</span><br/>

  <input class="btn" data-ng-click="save(model)" type="button" value="SAVE" />  
  </form>
```

and my save function.

```
$scope.save= function (model) {
    if ($scope.addRelation.$valid) {
        //form is valid- so save it to DB
    }
    else {
        //if form is not valid set $scope.addRelation.submitted to true
        $scope.addRelation.submitted=true;
    }
};
 })
```

Now, when i click on save button without filling anything all the errors(spans) are getting displayed. But i want to show red border for all the invalid fields.

I have tried following cases:

```
input.ng-dirty.ng-invalid{border:1px solid black;}
```

but this fails when a user click on submit button directly.(without touching input fields)

```
input.ng-invalid{border:1px solid black;}
```

this shows the red border as soon as user opens a signup form.

Please help.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Reference article: [Show red color border for invalid input fields angualrjs](http://coding-issues.blogspot.in/2015/09/show-red-border-for-invalid-inputs-fields-on-form-submit-angularjs.html)

I used ng-class on all input fields.like below

```
<input type="text" ng-class="{submitted:newEmployee.submitted}" placeholder="First Name" data-ng-model="model.firstName" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" required/>
```

when I click on save button I am changing **newEmployee.submitted** value to **true**(you can check it in my question). So when I click on save, a class named **submitted** gets added to all input fields(there are some other classes initially added by angularjs).

So now my input field contains classes like this

```
class="ng-pristine ng-invalid submitted"
```

now I am using below css code to **show red border on all invalid input fields**(after submitting the form)

```
input.submitted.ng-invalid
{
  border:1px solid #f00;
}
```

Thank you !!

**Update:**

We can add the ng-class at the form element instead of applying it to all input elements. So if the form is submitted, a new class(submitted) gets added to the form element. Then we can select all the invalid input fields using the below selector

```
form.submitted .ng-invalid
{
    border:1px solid #f00;
}
```

Comment: Cool! But why not add the `ng-class` at the `form` element? It is a single element, and we can declare the CSS rule selector as `form.submitted .ng-invalid`

Comment: @J.Bruni: Yes. We can apply. So that we can reduce the code also. Thanks for the great idea.. :)  I will update my answer.

Comment: I only managed to have it working when using `addRelation.$submitted` instead of simple `submitted` (Angular v1.3.16)

Comment: no need to add a ng-class, use : .ng-submitted .ng-invalid{...}

Comment: for some reason after clicking btn submiited class is not applied to any inputs

Comment: Why wait for them to submit the form before they find their errors? why not use `.ng-dirty .ng-invalid { ... }`??? That way they see the errors as they go,

Comment: I followed your tutorial but in form ng-class="{submitted:addForm.submitted}" ...the class is not getting applied..any reason

Comment: @user269867 did u do this ? "when I click on save button I am changing newEmployee.submitted value to true". are you using the same variable name in your controller ? can you please cross check once

Comment: @DevNull. Yes we can do that. But question clearly says "after submitting form". so this validation is after clicking on submit.

Answer (score 11):

you can use default ng-submitted is set if the form was submitted.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

example: http://jsbin.com/cowufugusu/1/

Comment: Can you detail and, if possible, provide an example of how your solution works?

Comment: form.ng-submitted input.ng-invalid {
  background: red;
}

Comment: Great solution, this apply a class to children inputs when the form is submitted. 

form.ng-submitted input.ng-invalid {
  background: red;
}. 

 form.ng-submitted: this class is added to the form it's when submitted
 input.ng-invalid: child input class when are invalid

So when the the form is submitted the form.ng-submitted is added to it. Now to access the children inputs use input.ng-invalid, looking for child invalid inputs this will add the style to invalid inputs with submitted form.

Answer (score 6):

I have created a [working CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lefsm) to demonstrate how you might accomplish your goals.

I added `ng-click` to the `<form>` and removed the logic from your button:

```
<form name="addRelation" data-ng-click="save(model)">
...
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="SAVE" />
```

Here's the updated template:

```
<section ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form class="well" name="addRelation" data-ng-click="save(model)">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" data-ng-model="model.firstName" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" required/><br/>
    <span class="text-error" data-ng-show="addRelation.submitted && addRelation.FirstName.$invalid">First Name is required</span><br/>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" data-ng-model="model.lastName" id="LastName" name="LastName" required/><br/>
    <span class="text-error" data-ng-show="addRelation.submitted && addRelation.LastName.$invalid">Last Name is required</span><br/>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" data-ng-model="model.email" id="Email" name="Email" required/><br/>
    <span class="text-error" data-ng-show="addRelation.submitted && addRelation.Email.$error.required">Email address is required</span>
    <span class="text-error" data-ng-show="addRelation.submitted && addRelation.Email.$error.email">Email address is not valid</span><br/>
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="SAVE" />  
  </form>
</section>
```

and controller code:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {  
  $scope.save = function(model) {
    $scope.addRelation.submitted = true;

    if($scope.addRelation.$valid) {
      // submit to db
      console.log(model); 
    } else {
      console.log('Errors in form data');
    }
  };
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Adam: Thanks for the reply. I checked the CodePan example you have created. when i click on save button errors are getting displayed under the invalid input fields. but i should get red border for all the invalid input fields(which is my actual requirement).